# Trigger automatic login after user registration using react front end with express back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

new here and a very very green react and node dev. My question is as follows:

1. Automatic login upon user registration
2. I believe this require the API to generate and send a JWS token to the front end. I've a vague idea of what needs to happen but the particulars of how to go about this elude me.

auth controller:

```
const db = require("../models");
const User = db.user;
const Role = db.role;

var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.email,
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8),
  });

  user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    if (req.body.roles) {
      Role.find(
        {
          name: { $in: req.body.roles },
        },
        (err, roles) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            return;
          }

          user.roles = roles.map((role) => role._id);
          user.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send({ message: err });
              return;
            }

            res.send({ message: "User was registered successfully!" });
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      Role.findOne({ name: "user" }, (err, role) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
          return;
        }

        user.roles = [role._id];
        user.save((err) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            return;
          }        

          res.send({ message: "User was registered successfully!" });
          
        
        });
      });
    }
  });
};

exports.signin = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
  })
    .populate("roles", "-__v")
    .exec((err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err });
        return;
      }

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({ message: "User Not found." });
      }

      var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
        req.body.password,
        user.password
      );

      if (!passwordIsValid) {
        return res.status(401).send({ message: "Invalid Password!" });
      }

      var token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400, // 24 hours
      });

      var authorities = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i++) {
        authorities.push("ROLE_" + user.roles[i].name.toUpperCase());
      }

      req.session.token = token;

      res.status(200).send({
        id: user._id,
        username: user.username,
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname,
        email: user.email,
        roles: authorities,
      });
    });
};

exports.signout = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    req.session = null;
    return res.status(200).send({ message: "You've been signed out!" });
  } catch (err) {
    this.next(err);
  }
};
```

auth jwt:

```
const config = require("../config/auth.config.js");
const db = require("../models");
const User = db.user;
const Role = db.role;

verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.session.token;

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({ message: "No token provided!" });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send({ message: "Unauthorized!" });
    }
    req.userId = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
};

isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.userId).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    Role.find(
      {
        _id: { $in: user.roles },
      },
      (err, roles) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
          return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
          if (roles[i].name === "admin") {
            next();
            return;
          }
        }

        res.status(403).send({ message: "Require Admin Role!" });
        return;
      }
    );
  });
};

isModerator = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.userId).exec((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    Role.find(
      {
        _id: { $in: user.roles },
      },
      (err, roles) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
          return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
          if (roles[i].name === "moderator") {
            next();
            return;
          }
        }

        res.status(403).send({ message: "Require Moderator Role!" });
        return;
      }
    );
  });
};

const authJwt = {
  verifyToken,
  isAdmin,
  isModerator,
};
module.exports = authJwt;
```

front end(metronic react typescript):

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {useFormik} from 'formik'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import {getUserByToken, register} from '../core/_requests'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {toAbsoluteUrl} from '../../../../_metronic/helpers'
import {PasswordMeterComponent} from '../../../../_metronic/assets/ts/components'
import {useAuth} from '../core/Auth'
import React from 'react'






const initialValues = {
  firstname: '',
  lastname: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  changepassword: '',
  acceptTerms: false,
}

const registrationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  firstname: Yup.string()
    .min(3, 'Minimum 3 symbols')
    .max(50, 'Maximum 50 symbols')
    .required('First name is required'),
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Wrong email format')
    .min(3, 'Minimum 3 symbols')
    .max(50, 'Maximum 50 symbols')
    .required('Email is required'),
  lastname: Yup.string()
    .min(3, 'Minimum 3 symbols')
    .max(50, 'Maximum 50 symbols')
    .required('Last name is required'),
  password: Yup.string()
    .min(3, 'Minimum 3 symbols')
    .max(50, 'Maximum 50 symbols')
    .required('Password is required'),
  changepassword: Yup.string()
    .required('Password confirmation is required')
    .when('password', {
      is: (val: string) => (val && val.length > 0 ? true : false),
      then: Yup.string().oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], "Password and Confirm Password didn't match"),
    }),
  acceptTerms: Yup.bool().required('You must accept the terms and conditions'),
})



export function Registration() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const {saveAuth, /*setCurrentUser*/} = useAuth()
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema: registrationSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values, {setStatus, setSubmitting}) => {
      setLoading(true)
      try {
          
        const {data: auth} = await register(
          values.email,
          values.firstname,
          values.lastname,
          values.password,
          values.changepassword
          
        )
        saveAuth(auth)
        //const {data: user} = await getUserByToken(auth.api_token)
        //setCurrentUser(user)
        
    
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        saveAuth(undefined)
        setStatus('The registration details are incorrect')
        setSubmitting(false)
        setLoading(false)
      }
    },
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    PasswordMeterComponent.bootstrap()
  }, [])

  return (
    <form
      className='form w-100 fv-plugins-bootstrap5 fv-plugins-framework'
      noValidate
      id='kt_login_signup_form'
      onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
    >
      {/* begin::Heading */}
      <div className='mb-10 text-center'>
        {/* begin::Title */}
        <h1 className='text-dark mb-3'>Create an Account</h1>
        {/* end::Title */}

        {/* begin::Link */}
        <div className='text-gray-400 fw-bold fs-4'>
          Already have an account?
          <Link to='/auth/login' className='link-primary fw-bolder' style={{marginLeft: '5px'}}>
            Forgot Password ?
          </Link>
        </div>
        {/* end::Link */}
      </div>
      {/* end::Heading */}

      {/* begin::Action */}
      <button type='button' className='btn btn-light-primary fw-bolder w-100 mb-10'>
        <img
          alt='Logo'
          src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/svg/brand-logos/google-icon.svg')}
          className='h-20px me-3'
        />
        Sign in with Google
      </button>
      {/* end::Action */}

      <div className='d-flex align-items-center mb-10'>
        <div className='border-bottom border-gray-300 mw-50 w-100'></div>
        <span className='fw-bold text-gray-400 fs-7 mx-2'>OR</span>
        <div className='border-bottom border-gray-300 mw-50 w-100'></div>
      </div>

      {formik.status && (
        <div className='mb-lg-15 alert alert-danger'>
          <div className='alert-text font-weight-bold'>{formik.status}</div>
        </div>
      )}

      {/* begin::Form group Firstname */}
      <div className='row fv-row mb-7'>
        <div className='col-xl-6'>
          <label className='class="form-label fw-bolder text-dark fs-6'>First name</label>
          <input
            placeholder='First name'
            type='text'
            autoComplete='off'
            {...formik.getFieldProps('firstname')}
            className={clsx(
              'form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid',
              {
                'is-invalid': formik.touched.firstname && formik.errors.firstname,
              },
              {
                'is-valid': formik.touched.firstname && !formik.errors.firstname,
              }
            )}
          />
          {formik.touched.firstname && formik.errors.firstname && (
            <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
              <div className='fv-help-block'>
                <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.firstname}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className='col-xl-6'>
          {/* begin::Form group Lastname */}
          <div className='fv-row mb-5'>
            <label className='form-label fw-bolder text-dark fs-6'>Last name</label>
            <input
              placeholder='Last name'
              type='text'
              autoComplete='off'
              {...formik.getFieldProps('lastname')}
              className={clsx(
                'form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid',
                {
                  'is-invalid': formik.touched.lastname && formik.errors.lastname,
                },
                {
                  'is-valid': formik.touched.lastname && !formik.errors.lastname,
                }
              )}
            />
            {formik.touched.lastname && formik.errors.lastname && (
              <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
                <div className='fv-help-block'>
                  <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.lastname}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          {/* end::Form group */}
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* end::Form group */}

      {/* begin::Form group Email */}
      <div className='fv-row mb-7'>
        <label className='form-label fw-bolder text-dark fs-6'>Email</label>
        <input
          placeholder='Email'
          type='email'
          autoComplete='off'
          {...formik.getFieldProps('email')}
          className={clsx(
            'form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid',
            {'is-invalid': formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email},
            {
              'is-valid': formik.touched.email && !formik.errors.email,
            }
          )}
        />
        {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email && (
          <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
            <div className='fv-help-block'>
              <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.email}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* end::Form group */}

      {/* begin::Form group Password */}
      <div className='mb-10 fv-row' data-kt-password-meter='true'>
        <div className='mb-1'>
          <label className='form-label fw-bolder text-dark fs-6'>Password</label>
          <div className='position-relative mb-3'>
            <input
              type='password'
              placeholder='Password'
              autoComplete='off'
              {...formik.getFieldProps('password')}
              className={clsx(
                'form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid',
                {
                  'is-invalid': formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password,
                },
                {
                  'is-valid': formik.touched.password && !formik.errors.password,
                }
              )}
            />
            {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password && (
              <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
                <div className='fv-help-block'>
                  <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.password}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          {/* begin::Meter */}
          <div
            className='d-flex align-items-center mb-3'
            data-kt-password-meter-control='highlight'
          >
            <div className='flex-grow-1 bg-secondary bg-active-success rounded h-5px me-2'></div>
            <div className='flex-grow-1 bg-secondary bg-active-success rounded h-5px me-2'></div>
            <div className='flex-grow-1 bg-secondary bg-active-success rounded h-5px me-2'></div>
            <div className='flex-grow-1 bg-secondary bg-active-success rounded h-5px'></div>
          </div>
          {/* end::Meter */}
        </div>
        <div className='text-muted'>
          Use 8 or more characters with a mix of letters, numbers & symbols.
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* end::Form group */}

      {/* begin::Form group Confirm password */}
      <div className='fv-row mb-5'>
        <label className='form-label fw-bolder text-dark fs-6'>Confirm Password</label>
        <input
          type='password'
          placeholder='Password confirmation'
          autoComplete='off'
          {...formik.getFieldProps('changepassword')}
          className={clsx(
            'form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid',
            {
              'is-invalid': formik.touched.changepassword && formik.errors.changepassword,
            },
            {
              'is-valid': formik.touched.changepassword && !formik.errors.changepassword,
            }
          )}
        />
        {formik.touched.changepassword && formik.errors.changepassword && (
          <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
            <div className='fv-help-block'>
              <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.changepassword}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* end::Form group */}

      {/* begin::Form group */}
      <div className='fv-row mb-10'>
        <div className='form-check form-check-custom form-check-solid'>
          <input
            className='form-check-input'
            type='checkbox'
            id='kt_login_toc_agree'
            {...formik.getFieldProps('acceptTerms')}
          />
          <label
            className='form-check-label fw-bold text-gray-700 fs-6'
            htmlFor='kt_login_toc_agree'
          >
            I Agree the{' '}
            <Link to='/auth/terms' className='ms-1 link-primary'>
              terms and conditions
            </Link>
            .
          </label>
          {formik.touched.acceptTerms && formik.errors.acceptTerms && (
            <div className='fv-plugins-message-container'>
              <div className='fv-help-block'>
                <span role='alert'>{formik.errors.acceptTerms}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* end::Form group */}

      {/* begin::Form group */}
      <div className='text-center'>
        <button
          type='submit'
          id='kt_sign_up_submit'
          className='btn btn-lg btn-primary w-100 mb-5'
          disabled={formik.isSubmitting || !formik.isValid || !formik.values.acceptTerms}
        >
          {!loading && <span className='indicator-label'>Submit</span>}
          {loading && (
            <span className='indicator-progress' style={{display: 'block'}}>
              Please wait...{' '}
              <span className='spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2'></span>
            </span>
          )}
        </button>
        <Link to='/auth/login'>
          <button
            type='button'
            id='kt_login_signup_form_cancel_button'
            className='btn btn-lg btn-light-primary w-100 mb-5'
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
      {/* end::Form group */}
    </form>
  )
}
```

If there's something else that is relevant please let me know and I will add. I Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Just Pass The Token to req.body after saving your users like this

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.email,
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8),
  });

  user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    if (req.body.roles) {
      Role.find(
        {
          name: { $in: req.body.roles },
        },
        (err, roles) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            return;
          }

          user.roles = roles.map((role) => role._id);
          user.save((err,data) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send({ message: err });
              return;
            }
        var token = jwt.sign({ id: data._id }, config.secret, {
    expiresIn: 86400, // 24 hours
  });

  var authorities = [];
  // This is what I mean
  req.session.token = token;

  res.status(200).send({
    id: user._id,
    username: user.username,
    firstname: user.firstname,
    lastname: user.lastname,
    email: user.email,
  });
});
            
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      Role.findOne({ name: "user" }, (err, role) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: err });
          return;
        }

        user.roles = [role._id];
        user.save((err,data) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err });
            return;
          }        

          var token = jwt.sign({ id: data._id }, config.secret, {
    expiresIn: 86400, // 24 hours
  });

  var authorities = [];
  // This is what I mean
  req.session.token = token;

  res.status(200).send({
    id: user._id,
    username: user.username,
    firstname: user.firstname,
    lastname: user.lastname,
    email: user.email,
  });
});
          
        
        });
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you Ogoh.cyril, this was bang on the mark!

Comment: I can now register and login via Postman and Rapid API, but cannot get react to redirect to the dashboard after login. When looking in dev tools im getting a 200 reponse to the login attempt, followed by a 404 not found. Any ideas as to why that might be? (should I post a new question for this follow up?)

Comment: Am not a Frontend person but I think you should have a function that check the auth response from the server __  use that response to redirect to the homepage if signup was successful

Answer (score 1):

it's simple, you only need call the signin function using the same email and password provided in the signup body instead of the `res.send({ message: "User was registered successfully!" });` because the res.send works like a return you need to send the jwt instead the success message.
i hope help you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, essentially the same as Ogoh.cyril, which was correct.